# openGL screensaver causes problems

Tags: opengl, qt4

I have an application written in QT4, that uses an openGL window.  It has been running happily for months.  Windows XP, service Pack 3,

Recently I was diddling with my screensaver, and happened to select the 3D text choice.  When I previewed it, the QT4 application seg-faulted immediately.  When I ran in the debugger,it is crashing in ig4dev32.dll, which is an intel graphics accelerator driver for Open GL.

When I do a similar test on a machine with an NVIDIA card, I (not surprisingly) get no problems.

I'm not really sure whether I'm asking for help, or insight, or whatever--has anybody ever seen it?  Google tells me others have seen it happen in gaming applications, but I see no references to developers having it happen to them.  Obviously, I can not use that screensaver, but I suspect the problem is "bigger" than that.  Ideas?

Comment: Can you run the screensaver preview and a known-good windowed OpenGL app without issues?

Comment: Good observation! It's just happend on client's laptop. Yous hint about Screen-saver is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I would start by reporting this to Intel. No doubt, they will not resolve it by the end of the week, but eventually. In the mean time, I'd also report it to Qt software, so see if they can trouble shoot it as well.

In the mean time, you know the issue and how to resolve it (no OpenGL screensavers). So all you have to do is to inform your customers. The best would be if the application itself could inform the customers, but detecting if a screensaver uses OpenGL or not does not seem feasable.

Perhaps you could do some additional tests. For instance, what happens if your application is run in paralell with, say, Google Earth in OpenGL mode?

Comment: I'm not sure this is an answer, but I wasn't really asking for one.  Per the previous comment and answer, I tried two things

1) "known good" openGL app and the screensaver--used Google Earth, crashed it!
2) Google Earth and my app--coincide happily, no problems--until I preview the screen saver, when both crash.

jch